# No .gitmodules file to add the line ignore = dirty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, git-submodules

So currently I am getting this error in my terminal when trying to commit/push:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
    modified:   guarded-headland-03173 (modified content)
```

Apparently, the answer is simply adding ignore = dirty to the .gitmodules file but the problem is that there is no .gitmodules for me.

Answer (score 0):

all I had to put into the terminal was:

```
git status --ignore-submodules=dirty
```

Comment: Thanks for adding your answer for reference. You can mark the answer as accepted.